# Why isn't my dataframe dropping duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to drop duplicates from my Pandas dataframe, but when I attempt it either nothing happens or the dataframe returns an empty dataframe.

I checked for duplicates using

```
sal_dupes = salaries[salaries.duplicated(keep=False)]
len(sal_dupes)
```

Which returns 34 rows that I confirmed look identical. I then tried

```
salaries = salaries.drop_duplicates()
```

Which does not remove the duplicates I found. If I try and use an inplace=True with drop_duplicates, it returns an empty dataframe. I'm expecting it to return the same dataframe with the duplicates removed.

Comment: When you use `inplace=True`, it modifies the dataframe and returns `None`. So don't assign the result in that case.

Comment: If it's not removing anything, they're not complete duplicates. Can you add a [mre]?

Comment: `Which does not remove the duplicates I found.` Are you saying it doesn't remove duplicates from `salaries`, or that it doesn't remove duplicates from `sal_dupes`?

Comment: Do as the previous 2 comments say, also check the dataframe index.

Comment: Note that `duplicates()` with `keep=False` returns both rows in a pair of duplicates, but `drop_duplicates()` without `keep=False` keeps one of the duplicates (it defaults to `keep='first'`). So you're not going to drop all 34 rows that were returned in the first snippet.

Comment: As stated in the comment, `duplicates()` with `keep=False` will return number of all duplicates so the actual number of dropped rows will be at least half smaller.

The fact that you get an empty dataframe and not `None` makes me think that there is some other code in between your quoted code that modifies the `salaries` dataframe before dropping duplicates.